# Action bar without items

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I need to use action bar in my application but don't use any items in it or the menu, is something like this possible?
Also action bar that I am using has custom view set to true and draws my custom view with a centered text.

Things I already tried were:
Just not putting items in menu xml, this doesn't work since custom view is not shown.
Hiding single item in the menu with following code

```
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.my_item);
            item.setVisible(false);
    return true;
}
```

This also doesn't work because there is no custom view again.

Is there some trick to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You add the custom view using one of the `ActionBar.setCustomView()` methods. Then you can either leave that method empty or remove it altogether. You may need to also call `ActionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM, ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM)`

Comment: Thank you for suggestions but I think you didn't really understand the question... Or I am not quite getting what you are saying in your answer so if you could please explain in more details. I know how to add a custom view but the problem is it's not showing when there are no items in the menu.